# Good rsync-with-version-history solution for mission-critical remote backups on Windows?

Tags: rsync

I need to back up some huge files (100GB) and a zillion little ones (2,000,000 x 50k) over the internet via SSL, from one Windows Server 2008 box to another.

What I want is to have the directory structure on the backup server mirror the production server -- but with a version history. rsync does the first part, and I know a few products combine rsync with a version history, but I don't know which ones are really ready for prime-time.

My plan was to use [Syncrify](http://web.synametrics.com/Syncrify.htm), but since nobody seems to have any experience with it, I'm looking for other ideas.

Comment: If you clarify your question with more platform and use case details, you are likely to get a more specific answer. I threw out a general thought about maybe using a version control system instead of rsync in my answer below, but this may not fit your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncrify is good and should work. We use it to backup our web server and it works fine. However, I have not te

Comment: Danny, can you tell me more about what you're backing up?

Comment: Just wanted to close the loop on this: we've been using Syncrify for over a year now, and it's been easy and reliable. Also, their support is excellent.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) will fulfill your needs nicely.  I have used it to do linux->linux and windows->windows and windows->linux backups.  It keeps the current version as an exact mirror of the source.  Then uses a reverse-differencing algorithm to store prior versions.  It uses the rsync network protocol for efficient use of the network.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to backup with a version history as in being able to restore older versions of backed up files, you should probably look at using a versioning system such as `git` or `subversion` instead of a copy system like rsync. Less recommended alternatives would be to manage your own deltas with something like incremental tar files.

If I misunderstood what you want for "version history", please clarify your question, but `rsync` itself is not a tool equipped to keep a history of either it's own actions over time or versions of files as they change through time. It is just a copy/synchronization tool. A very good one at that, but a very specific use tool.

Edit: Another tool that might suit your needs is `rsnapshot`, which uses rsync as a copy tool but keeps track of multiple versions so that you can backtrack to older "snapshots".

Comment: Caleb, thanks for the version-control suggestion. AFAIK, git and svn don't have the bandwidth-saving delta storage that rsync does. rsnapshot would be perfect... if it ran on Windows.

Comment: wouldn't volume shadow copy on the remote end achieve this, given enough storage space?

Comment: Use rsnapshot with Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

My rep is to low to comment so I will add and answer...
rsnapshot does run on windows!  http://blog.gingerlime.com/rsnapshot-server-on-windows
hope your problem is already solved, but if it isn't, I hope this helps

Comment: I would also vote up the question and other answer but...